# How to execute migration in Yii2 framework?

Tags: php, docker-compose, yii2, database-migration

I'm trying to start Yii2 advanced project using docker. This is my first project in Yii2 and I don't know what might be the problem.

There are a few commands in a DockerFile in a frontend directory. These enable me to download npm, composer etc.

I'm running the following command in console:

```
docker-compose run --rm backend init
```

Everything is just fine, so I'm changing access data in the main-local.php file:

```
'components' => [
   'db' => [
      'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
      'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3396;dbname=pdo_local',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'charset' => 'utf8',
      'enableQueryCache' => false,
      'emulatePrepare' => false,
   ]
]
```

I'm running the next command:

```
docker-compose run --rm backend yii migrate
```

and there is an ERROR:

```
usermod: no changes
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.32)

Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Failed to instantiate component or class "db".'

in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:449

Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(374): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('db')
#1 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(159): yii\di\Container->build('db', Array, Array)
#2 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Instance.php(167): yii\di\Container->get('db')
#3 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Instance.php(137): yii\di\Instance->get(NULL)
#4 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/MigrateController.php(183): yii\di\Instance::ensure(Object(yii\di\Instance), 'yii\\db\\Connecti...')
#5 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(155): yii\console\controllers\MigrateController->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#6 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(164): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#7 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): yii\console\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#8 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(180): yii\base\Module->runAction('migrate', Array)
#9 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(147): yii\console\Application->runAction('migrate', Array)
#10 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
#11 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/yii(37): yii\base\Application->run()
#12 {main}
```

Do you have any ideas how to execute migration?

Comment: the database settings you provided above are in `common/config`?, if not they should be there otherwise you need to add the settings for every app

Comment: Yes. That data is in `common/config/main.php` and `common/config/main-local.php`